# How does my application check whether the user has allowed the app to post on his behalf on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my Facebook application, I am requesting 3 scopes: `email,publish_stream,publish_action`

I am using the `FB.login` function.  These 2 steps pop up.

When the user clicks "Cancel" in the first step, FB.login will show "status: unknown" as the response object.

However, when user clicks cancel in the second step, FB.login shows it as "status:connected" and treats it as if the user accepted everything.

How does my app determine if the user denied the 2nd step?

---

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do this via the graph api:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
    console.log(response);
} );
```

example:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            create_note: 1,
            installed: 1,
            photo_upload: 1,
            publish_stream: 1,
            share_item: 1,
            status_update: 1,
            video_upload: 1,
        }
    ]
}
```

see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: But let's assume that the user denied that 2nd step.  How do I make the user "Allow" that again? Can I pop up a new dialog for that?

Comment: yes, just do as you initial do, all rights the user has not given you already are requested.

Answer (score 0):

Use Users.hasAppPermission to check if a user has those permissions.

See : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.ApiClient.users_hasAppPermission